# Directshow File play back error

Tags: c++, directshow

Learning how to play a video file using DirectShow SDK provided by Microsoft. In the Documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389098(v=vs.85).aspx it states that:

- this simple console application plays an audio or video file

However when I run the application there are no compile errors, but there are run time errors. The run time errors is that the video does not run after the C++ has compiled, but the command prompt does show up but it is just an empty black box. I used the header file and the linker

```
  #include <dshow.h>
  #pragma comment(lib, "Strmids.lib")
```

Again, I used the same code from Microsoft documentation library located here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389098(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What kind of video file are you trying to use?

Comment: .wmv is the video I am using for this file

Comment: I asked because I remember DirectShow being most happy with simple AVI movies; you may want to try other files. And definitely add error checking and/or debug the program to find out if any of the hr results has a failure code

Comment: You have to make sure that DD is able to build a graph for your file up to video and audio renderers. Use http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/ to check.

Comment: To validate if you can render properly your wmv file, use a tool like GraphEdit or 
[Graph Studio](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/).

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib, "Strmiids.lib")`, Strmiids and not Strmids

Comment: For the rest of the issues, you simply don't provide sufficient and essential information.

Comment: Roman I have added the pragma comment of "Strmiids.lib", and the project fail to work. How can I link the library with the project